# StaticResource is null even though it's defined in XAML?

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, com-interop

I've got a bit of a niche scenario which I'm fully not expecting anyone to solve, but thought I'd give it a shot:

I have a Windows Forms User Control, which contains a single `ElementHost`control that has it's `Child` property set to a WPF / XAML user control.

I'm getting some strange behaviour whereby the XAML contains something that looks like this:

```
<UserControl>
  <UserControl.Resources>
    <somenamespace:myresource x:Key="foo" />
  </UserControl.Resources>
  <Grid DataContext="{StaticResource foo}">
   ...
  </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

I get a `XamlParseException` at runtime, asking me to Provide a value, even though it's clearly defined above.

I can see `InitializeComponent()` is being called, but that's as far as I can step.

In my code behind, in the WPF / XAML user control, if before `InitializeComponent()` is called I add:
`this.Resources["foo"] = new myresource()` everything works great again.

Just to confuse matters even further, this only happens when I use Visual Studio 2015 to compile the code - compiling using VS2013 (on the same machine/no solution changes whatsoever) works perfectly.

Has anyone got any ideas, or even helps on how to debug this?

Comment: In your XAML is it `x:key` or `x:Key`?

Comment: has your resource a default constructor ?

Comment: @dkozl Sorry It would've been `x:Key` - I typed the whole thing up in the stackoverflow textbox.

Comment: @maxp I have no VS2015 to test this nor I am aware of such problem so I can only suspect that it has something to do with order things are initialized. Did you try using `DynamicResource` instead?

Comment: can you give us the exact error description?